# MailJet nested loops

Tags: loops, email, html-email, templating-engine, mailjet

we are building our emails with mailJet which works fine so far. Our current problem is, that we would like to have a loop within a loop within a loop (so nested loops) the first loop works fine, and also the second inner loop is working fine, but the third one isn't working anymore:

```
{% for trip in var:trips %}
{{trip.id}}

{% for tripSegment in trip.tripSegments %}

{% for tripBreak in tripSegment.breaks %}
{{tripBreak.duration}}
{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}

Distance: {{trip.totalDistance}} km

{% endfor %}
```

This is in our template. If I remove the inner loop with the breaks, everything is fine.

If I enable the Template Error Reporting I get the following message:

```
X-MJ-ErrorMessage: "tripSegment.breaks" is not an array value
```

but if I try to print it with {{tripSegment.breaks}} I get the message:

```
X-MJ-ErrorMessage: Array values cannot be printed: tripSegment.breaks
```

and the field is definetly an array, like the trips or tripSegments, so basically it should work.

What am I doing wrong for nested loops in MailJet?

Edit:

My Object Structure, I send to Mailjet looks like this:

```
"Vars": {
    "trips": [
        "id": 1,
        "tripSegments":[
            {
                "id":2,
                "distance": 100,
                "breaks":[
                    {
                        "duration":15
                    },{
                        "duration":20
                    }
                ]
            },{
                "id":3,
                "distance": 200,
                "breaks":[
                    {
                        "duration":10
                    },{
                        "duration":30
                    }
                ]
            },{
                "id":4,
                "distance": 200,
                "breaks":[
                ]
            },
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we were in discussion with the MailJet Support [1], it turns out that there is a bug in the WYSIWYG editor of MailJet.

the multiple nested loops work, if you use them within a HTML Block and not directly in the WYSIWYG Editor.

They are working on that.

[1] https://app.mailjet.com/support/ticket/21e111b3be8630214cc082845f6cf976

Comment: When clicking on your link: `This ticket was opened with another Maijet account. Please sign in with the good account to access this ticket.`. Can you provide the ticket answer on this post please?

Comment: I'm sorry, as I do not work at this company anymore, I do not have access to this account anymore....

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to loop on tripSegment.breaks, it should be represented as an array and not as an object.

I managed to create a sample which works for me with the same values you use.

```
'Vars' => [ 
        "trips"=>[ 
            'trips1' =>[
        'id'=> 123,
        'totalDistance'=> 10, 
        'tripSegments' => [ 
            ['breaks' =>[['duration'=>1],['duration'=> 2]]],
            ['breaks' =>[['duration'=>1],['duration'=> 2]]],
            ['breaks' =>[['duration'=>1],['duration'=> 2]]]
                          ]
                       ]    
                  ]
      ]
```

Comment: I Adjusted my question to show you my object structure, which for me looks totally fine

Answer (score 2):

I find this has nothing to with the WYSIWYG Editor, remains a bug in Mailjet's templating language, and is easily reproducible. Use Postman or other API testing tool to send the following JSON to the **send** endpoint (*make sure you add your API key credentials via Basic Auth*):

`POST https://api.mailjet.com/v3/send`

```
{
    "FromEmail": "me@example.com",
    "FromName": "Me",
    "Subject": "Test",
    "MJ-TemplateLanguage": true,
    "MJ-TemplateErrorReporting": "me@example.com",
    "MJ-TemplateErrorDeliver": "deliver",
    "Recipients": [
        { "Email": "me@example.com" }
    ],
    "Html-part": "<ul>{% for project in var:commissions.projects %}<li>{{project.name}}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>",
    "Vars": {
        "commissions": { "total": "235,000", "projects": [] }
    }
  }
```

You'll get an error report via email back to you with the content `No value for "commissions.projects"` instead of it simply passing through the loop silently.