# Mailjet - Multidimensionnal array in template

Tags: php, arrays, mailjet

I'm using **mailjet** to send transactionnal e-mails with the **APIv3**.

The mail is sent correctly until i want to use the **second level of a multidimensionnal array** variable.

Here is the working bit of template :

```
{%for category in var:categories%}

{{category.title}} :

{% endfor %}
```

This shows the categories like *Titre colonne 1* as expected.

But if i have this :

```
{%for category in var:categories%}

{{category.title}} :

{%for item in category.items%}

{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

I receive this error from mailjet:

> unknown node ## near ## 0px 0;">{%for item i ##

The array (value of variable categories) seems fine to me :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Titre colonne 1
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Item 1
                            [value] => 5
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Item 2
                            [value] => 10
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Titre colonne 2
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Item 3
                            [value] => 20
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Titre colonne 3
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Item 4
                            [value] => 40
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Item 5
                            [value] => 80
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Item 6
                            [value] => 160
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Item 7
                            [value] => 320
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => Titre colonne 4
            [items] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Does anyone sees where i did a mistake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated on an other mailjet related question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40014622/3005056), mailjet have trouble with multi-loop in there WYSIWYG.

I've done it by adding HTML bloc and editing it.

Now i have to find how to detect empty array...